# OSX 10.13 DOTNET RUN System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such file or directory

Tags: .net-core

When executing dotnet run -c release in my terminal on OSX 10.13, I get the following error:

```
../../Properties/launchSettings.json...
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): No such file or 
directory
at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, 
String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean 
redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& 
stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean shouldThrow)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Start()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.RunCommand.Run(String[] args)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry 
telemetryClient)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

.NET Command Line Tools (2.2.0-preview1-007582)

Product Information:
Version: 2.2.0-preview1-007582
Commit SHA-1 hash: 4845efe2ea

Runtime Environment:
OS Name: Mac OS X
OS Version: 10.13
OS Platform: Darwin
RID: osx.10.12-x64
Base Path: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.0-preview1-007582/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version : 2.1.0-preview1-25919-02
Build : 96a1025de48784825ac61e45ece24a4343e0bf01

The runtime identifier is set for OSX 10.12 as directed on the Microsoft documents.
The project works on Windows 10, just not on any OSX device.
The launchSettings.json file does exist. If I copy and nano the file, it will edit the file. I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: Do you set anything in the csproj? the only valid RID for 2.0+ is `osx-x64`, no ´10.*` anymore.

Comment: I've tried both and no difference. Not setting an RID crashes the app with other errors so it needs to be there.

Answer (score 2):

dotnetcore 2.0.3 and 2.1 have this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6397

There is a . in our project name and it's causing the issue.

It's currently reopened as it has not been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed and are using a version of the .NET Core Runtime that supports macOS High Sierra (10.13).

Since you are building a self-contained app, make sure that you set the `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` to a recent version to ensure that you include all the assets necessary to run on High Sierra.

For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.8</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or if you are using .NET Core 1.1:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.5</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

.NET Core 2.0 always supported High Sierra, but to get the newest runtime for self-contained apps, you currently also need to set this property:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.0.3</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```